# Is it valid to instantiate windowListener interface?

Tags: java, swing, interface, awt, windowlistener

`WindowListener` is an interface?  But how instantiation is valid as per the following? We can not instantiate interface right?

```
WindowListener l1=new WindowListener() {

        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

Comment: See [*How to Write Window Listeners*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is creating a new anonymous class that implements the WindowListener interface.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Then for the following, new anonymous class that extends  WindowAdapter?
WindowListener l=new WindowAdapter() {
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
}   Am i correct?